# vba AutoFill method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find month of a date in column A and paste the result to column B. They both have headers, column A’s is Date and column B’s is Month. I would like to have vba codes simply calculating the month of column A.

Here are my codes so far,

```
Sub Month()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Cells(2, "B") = "=Month(A2)"
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

But I keep getting  AutoFill method of range class failed error and I tried to change the AutoFill type but it won’t work. If you guys know a faster way to do it, let me know, too. (not excel functions, plz)

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: What worksheet is *active* when you run this code? And what is the `Selection` object when you run this code? And is the sheet protected in any way?

Comment: I tried both but they they are still giving me the same error. I think I was trying to select ws.Cells(2, "B") = "=Month(A2)"

Comment: It only filled out B2 and then it gives me the error.

Comment: I modified the codes but it's still not working, having the same error.

Comment: I see what the problem is. Will revise my answer.

Comment: this should work. thanks for the comments and idea. I fixed it. it works now

Answer (score 1):

This code will fail if the value of `lastrow` is 2. You need to add some logic to account for that.  Also revised to use [better method of finding "last row"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

```
Sub month()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim startCell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
With ws
    Set startCell = .Cells(2, 2) ' or .Range("B2")
    lastrow = startCell.EntireColumn.Find("*", AFter:=startCell, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If lastrow = startCell.Row Then lastrow = lastrow + 1
    startCell.Formula = "=Month(A2)"
    startCell.AutoFill Range(startCell, startCell.Cells(lastrow)), xlFillDefault
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

"The destination must include the source range". Refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx). So please select the cell. If you want to apply formula to cell use `.Formula = "=Month(A2)"`

```
Sub Month()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells(2, "B") = "=Month(A2)"
    ws.Cells(2, "B").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```